# How to make a timer with tkinter?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, timer

I'm trying to make a timer that shutdowns my computer running linux. To select the time I'm using spinbox. So the idea is to select the amount of the time in the spinbox and then add to the command `sudo shutdown -P` + 15 min *(e.g example).*

Till now it just shuts down and I can't a simple way to do this.

[timer program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmun0.jpg)

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import time

def shutdown():
    hrs = spin1.get()
    command1 = ('sudo shutdown -P')
    #sum1 = command1 + hrs
    os.system('sudo shutdown -P') + ('hrs')
    print(os.system)

def cancel():
    command = ('sudo shutdown -c')
    os.system('sudo shutdown -c')
    print(command)



'''def hrs():
    spn1 = spin1.get()
    dsp1 = spn1
    lbltime ['text'] = dsp1'''

entry_width = 2
win = Tk()

spin1 = IntVar()
spn = IntVar()

win.title('SHUTDOWN')
win.geometry('300x250+300+150')
lbl = Label(win, text='SET YOUR SHUTDOWN')
lbl.place(x=80, y=30)


spin1 = Spinbox(win, from_=00, to=23, font=('arial',26,'bold'), width= entry_width, textvariable=spin1)
spin1.insert(0, '00')
spin1.place(x=130, y=60)

setup = Button(win, text='SET TIMER', font=('arial',16,'bold'), command=lambda :shutdown())
setup.place(x=90, y=130)

cnc = Button(win, text='CANCEL', font=('verdana',10, 'bold'),command= lambda :cancel())
cnc.place(x=120, y=180)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: See related question: [Pause and continue stopwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787958/pause-and-continue-stopwatch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add your `hrs` (minutes chosen by user) to your command you could either simply add it to your existing string command using `+` or using `format()` as I've shown in my solution. Also when running commands with `sudo` you need to enter password, to do this automatically you could use -S argument which makes sudo read the password from STDIN, here `"mypassword"`.

```
def shutdown():
    hrs = spin1.get()
    sd_command = 'echo mypassword | sudo -S shutdown -P +' + hrs # both will work
    sd_command = 'echo mypassword | sudo -S shutdown -P +{}'.format(hrs)
    os.system(command)
    print(command)

def cancel():
    cancel_command = 'echo mypassword | sudo -S shutdown -c'
    os.system(cancel_command)
    print(cancel_command)
```

---

If you want to add message about shutdown schedule you need to add another Label, here `shutdown_schedule` which will display content of `var_schedule` which is tkinter string variable, that will be modified when user will schedule or cancel shutdown.

```
def shutdown():
    hrs = spin1.get()

    sd_time = time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime(time.time() + 60*int(hrs)))
    var_schedule.set('Shutdown scheduled for {}'.format(sd_time))

    sd_command = 'echo mypassword | sudo -S shutdown -P +' + hrs # both will work
    sd_command = 'echo mypassword | sudo -S shutdown -P +{}'.format(hrs)
    os.system(command)
    print(command)

def cancel():
    var_schedule.set('Shutdown not scheduled yet')

    cancel_command = 'echo mypassword | sudo -S shutdown -c'
       os.system(cancel_command)
    print(cancel_command)

var_schedule = StringVar()
var_schedule.set('Shutdown not scheduled yet')

shutdown_schedule = Label(win, textvariable=var_schedule)
shutdown_schedule.place(x=130, y=30)
```

Comment: Thank you it works! Now i just can't insert the message "Shutdown scheduled for..." in the new label. I tried everything but it doesn't show.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Hi! I got this error message:
"sd_time = time.strftime('%H:%M'), time.localtime(time.time() + int(60 * hrs))
OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t"

Comment: Updated creating predicted time, try now.

Comment: Ok. Now it's working like i wants before. \o/ Thanks for your help. I have to changed some parts in S sudo 'cos i was getting errors about no tty.
Now comes the stage to add pictures and make the
the appearance beautiful for my timer.